# Facing error to evaluate spider 1.0 dataset using orca-2-7B model, hugging face transformers

Tags: stanford-nlp, huggingface-transformers, llama, nlp-question-answering, orca

I am trying to evaluate Spider 1.0 dataset using Orca-2-7B model, hugging face transformer but this error is showing. Is that anything wrong in my code? I follow this instructions to run this "run_ocra6.py" script.

Steps:

```
git lfs
git lfs install
pip install torch
pip install transformers
pip install sentencepiece
pip install transformers --upgrade
pip install protobuf
pip install accelerate
python run_orca6.py
```